# Receive money from US Client to Myself in India by selling services

Tags: india, money-transfer

I have some clients in United States that I am doing some software development for them.  How can I receive money from them. What are the exact legal steps that I need to take so this works perfectly?  Paypal is a big headache that we donno when it blocks our account.  So, what are the steps needed for this ?  (like registering a company, and what kind of company to register(ltd, private ltd etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can receive funds from US Client as an individual. There is no legal requirement for you to have a company. If the transactions are large say more than 20 lacs in a year, its advisable to open a Private Ltd. Although its simple opening & Registering a company [A CA or a Laywer would get one at a nominal price of Rs 5000] you can do yourself.

Whatever be the case, its advisable to have seperate accounts for this business / professional service transactions. Maintain proper records of the funds received. There are certain benefits you can claim, a CA can help you. Paying taxes in Advance is your responsibility and hence make sure you keep paying every quarter as advance tax.

Related questions

[Indian citizen working from India as freelancer for U.S.-based company. How to report the income & pay tax in India?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/indian-citizen-working-from-india-as-freelancer-for-u-s-based-company-how-to-r/13937#13937)

[Freelancer in India working for Swiss Company](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/freelancer-in-india-working-for-swiss-company)

[Freelancing to UK company from India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/freelancing-to-uk-company-from-india)

[How do I account for money paid to colleagues out of my professional income?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/how-do-i-account-for-money-paid-to-colleagues-out-of-my-professional-income)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how tech savvy your client is you could potentially use bitcoin. There is some take of indian regulators stopping bitcoin exchanges, meaning it might be hard to get your money out in your local country but the lack of fees to transfer and not getting killed on the exchange rate every time has a huge impact, especially if your individual transaction sizes are not huge.